# Can an iMac be used as a replacement for laptop?

Tags: macbook-pro, imac

I am thinking of buying an iMac as a replacement for my laptop. Do iMac have batteries like in a laptop or do we have to always keep it plugged-in to power while using?

Comment: https://www.apple.com/imac/specs/ has all the technical details :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

iMac is a consumer desktop computer and doesn't come with a built in battery. Neither is it possible to install batteries in an iMac.

Unlike a laptop (MacBook) an iMac is not portable and have to be kept plugged in to a power source while in use.

Whether an iMac can be used as a replacement for a laptop depends on your specific workflow. It runs the same operating as a Apple laptop (MacBook) and comes with mostly comparable hardware and feature set.